# How to build a list of objects from JQuery selectors and send in Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**1. Explanation of my screen and fields:**

Considering each value on the screen as **editable** inputs with the names: `name_{id of the row}`

```
ordinary_1 = 4.5
ordinary_2 = 3.8
overtimeApproved = false
overtimeApproved = true
overtime15_1 = 0
overtime15_2 = 0
overtime20_1 = 0
overtime20_2 = 0
```

**Table on the screen:**
[image]

When I click on **Approve button**, I will need to build a json with the values when "**Overtime Approved is checked**", as below:

```
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Ordinary": "3.8",
  "OvertimeApproved": "true",
  "Overtime15": "0"
  "Overtime20": "0"
}
```

To build this Json I need to select the fields using JQuery Selectors and then send the Json in an Ajax command to my MVC in order to update those fields.

I don't know how to use editable datatables, and the way I explained might be the quickest solution.

So I need:

1. Build that Json using JQuery Selector, each() command, etc.
2. Send that in an Ajax (This I know how to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [];
$("#tableID tr").each(function() {
    var cols = $(this).find("td");
    data.push({
        Id: cols.eq(0).prop('name').split('_')[1],
        Ordinary: cols.eq(0).text(),
        OvertimeApproved: cols.eq(1).find(":checkbox").is(":checked") ? "true" : "false",
        Overtime15: cols.eq(2).text(),
        Overtime20: cols.eq(3).text()
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I convert data to Json or is it already in Json format? @Barmar

Comment: How can I select only when in the row there is an ".overtimeapproval".is.(:checked)   ??

Comment: You can use `var json = JSON.stringify(data)` to convert it to a JSON string.

Comment: `$("#tableID tr:has(.overtimeapproval:checked)")`